# C: How to free a struct ** that contains fields which are char* and ENUM (int)?

Tags: c, struct, enums

My code contains the `struct BeforeTriag` which is from type `Patient**` .
here is the structs and it's fields:

```
typedef struct{
char Id[ID_SIZE];
char Name[NAME_SIZE];
char LastName[NAME_SIZE];
char PhoneNum[PHONE_SIZE];
STATUS Status;
char Address[ADDRESS_SIZE];
}Patient;
```

Here is my initilization and allocation:

```
Patient** BeforeTriag = NULL;
int* BeforeTriagSize[1] = { 0 };

BeforeTriag = (Patient**)malloc(sizeof(Patient*));
if (!(BeforeTriag))
{
    printf("ERROR!Out of memory!");
    exit(1);
}

*BeforeTriag = (Patient*)malloc((PatientArraySize)* sizeof(Patient));
if (!(*BeforeTriag)){
    printf("ERROR!Out of memory!");
    exit(1);
}
```

here i'm tring to free each field in the struct:

```
    for (i = 0; i < (*BeforeTriagSize); i++){
    free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Id);
    free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Name);
    free((BeforeTriag)[i]->LastName);
    free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Address);
    free((BeforeTriag)[i]->PhoneNum);
    }

    free(BeforeTriag);
```

When I am debugging it crush on the first row of the free id:
        `free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Id);`

What should i do to free as proper?

Answer (score 2):

The individual fields within `BeforeTriag[i]` were not dynamically allocated by themselves, so you can't free them.  You need to free the struct as a whole, because that's what was allocated:

```
for (i = 0; i < (*BeforeTriagSize); i++){
    free(BeforeTriag[i]);
}
free(BeforeTriag);
```

Comment: it's still crushing in the line: free(BeforeTriag[i]);
Error saying: corrupted stack

Comment: @daniel_a Then we need to see more on how you're managing your arrays.  Specifically, how you expand the array and keep track of the size, and also how you read from / write to it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < (*BeforeTriagSize); i++){
free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Id);
free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Name);
free((BeforeTriag)[i]->LastName);
free((BeforeTriag)[i]->Address);
free((BeforeTriag)[i]->PhoneNum);
}
```

Because they are not dynamically allocated.
But you have to free `BeforeTriag[i]` inside the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < (*BeforeTriagSize); i++){
    free(BeforeTriag[i]);
}
free(BeforeTriag);
```

Answer (score 0):

While @dbush and @RolBrok already pointed out correctly that there's no need to free the individual members, there is another bug in your code:

`int* BeforeTriagSize[1] = { 0 };`

This line initalizes a int ** to zero. I'm not really sure why you want this variable to be in an array, but anyway, the correct way to declare it would be

`int BeforeTriagSize[1] = { 0 };`

(If you only need one value for BeforeTriagSize anyway, just declare it as an int!)

Edit: 
Another thing you should look closer into is the way you're allocating memory for your structs:
`*BeforeTriag = (Patient*)malloc((PatientArraySize)* sizeof(Patient));`

With this you're always writing to the same pointer. So when you are allocating the memory for the second struct, you are overwriting the position of the first one, basically causing a memory leak.

Consider something along the line of 
`BeforeTriag[BeforeTriagSize++] = (Patient*)malloc((PatientArraySize)* sizeof(Patient));`

This ensures that you are writing to a new position in your array every time. (Assuming you changed BeforeTriagSize to an int - if you need to hand it over as a pointer to some functions just use the address operator (&))

Comment: i fix it but when i sent the BeforeTriagSize as argument to functions i sent it with int*. just the initilazition i fixed but it still not working :(